# Bad Access/Pointer Issue in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got the following bit of code:

```
Byte * tokenOut = NULL;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Tknout); i++)
{
    tokenOut[i * 2] = (Tknout[i] >> 8);
    tokenOut[(i * 2) + 1] = (Tknout[i] & 0xFF);
}
```

But it generates an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error upon running when I try to update tokenOut. I'd appreciate if somebody could tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I just happen to be using it in Objective C. Could you possibly suggest a solution?

Comment: `outToken` is `NULL`, so any attempt to index into it is meaningless ;)

Comment: That was XCodes suggested fix. Initially I just had it as "Byte * outToken;".

Comment: Yes because that comment is SUPER helpful Hot Licks.

Comment: Get a book on the C programming language.  Go through a few tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Try

```
Byte whatever;
Byte *outToken = &whatever;
// Do the rest.
```

Now there is valid memory for you to write to.

Except you will still have issues because you will write past the end of your variable.  So maybe you wanted an array?

sizeof(outTkn) will return 1 (1 byte)